# Extjs + PHP enhance performance by increasing Java heap size

Tags: javascript, php, performance, extjs, measurement

I'm implementing a web application (Extjs + php). I was trying to enhance the performance especially for retrieving data using Extjs store + php. I tried increasing Java head size.. I see there is a huge deference in receiving php results timing:

Before (Memory: 4 GB):

[image]

After (Memory: 11 GB):

[image]

But I cannot notice any deference in displaying result time (on client side). They are almost the same. Do you recommend any good tool for measuring the load deference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the heap size on your server will have no impact on the client rendering time.

Tracking performance on the client side is no simple task. There are some excellent general tools that will help you monitor the front end:

- Chrome Developer Tools -> Profiles allows you to profile stats within
  your browser
- http://yslow.org/faq/ -> Gives you an overview of common
  metrics that impact performance
- http://www.webpagetest.org ->
  provides a variety of browsers and locations from which you can test
  your side (see common metrics from IE, Chrome, FF, etc and from the
  US, EU, etc).
- [Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1205784?hl=en&ref_topic=1282106) -> a very powerful tool to track
  user usage and responsiveness together.

To understand the specific amount of time it take to render something on the client, you need to instrument your code. The most simple way to do this is a console.log with the start time and one with the end time and compare the two. This can give you an idea, but performance metrics on the client side vary widely depending on what else your computer is doing or what browser you use.

For the most useful metrics you need to continually monitor your code from your development environment through production (yes, production). There is no substitute for measuring the performance your users are experiencing on your production site - they have a much more diverse set of environments than you would be able to create on your own.